# MySQL and INSERT IGNORE

Tags: php, mysql, insert, sql-insert

I am trying to read from a database in MySQL and insert my data in another database in MySQL .

my first table is like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `link` (
  `_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `link` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6149 ;
```

and the second table is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `country` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `Logo` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Name_3` (`Name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8457 ;
```

There are about 6114 rows in first table that I'm trying to insert to second using this code

```
<?php

$tmp = mysqli_connect(******, *****, ****, *****); // First table in here

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$main = mysqli_connect(*****, *****, ****, ******); //Second table in here

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$req = "SELECT country  FROM link";
$result = mysqli_query($tmp, $req) or die( mysqli_error($tmp) );

echo "-> ".mysqli_num_rows($result)."<br>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $con = $row["country"];

    $req = "INSERT IGNORE INTO country (Name) VALUES ('$con')";
    mysqli_query($main, $req) or die( mysqli_error($main) ) ;

}
?>
```

problem is the php code works but for 6114 take a very long time which I can't afford .
what is causing the code to take this long to work ? is it the "INSERT IGNORE" ?
is there any way I can do this faster ?

Comment: Are these databases on the same server?  If so, have you considered [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html)?

Comment: yes databases are on the same server , no I have not , is that faster then "INSERT IGNORE" ?

Comment: `IGNORE` doesn't speed anything up (and can be used with `INSERT ... SELECT` too) - it merely ignores any errors that occur during insertion.

Comment: It may be required due to shorter column width.

Comment: are the database tables indexed? I found this can significantly speed up data read times

Comment: first table yes , second one is not indexed , will indexing the writing table speed up the code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the databases are on the same server, you can simply use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html) (which avoids having to bring the data into PHP and loop over the results executing separate database commands for each of them, so will be *considerably* faster):

```sql
INSERT INTO db2.country (Name) SELECT country FROM db1.link
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try a create an index on column "country" of table Link.